# How can I get the exact solution of this equation (inequality equation)?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve the equation and inequality equation 
$$\sqrt{8\cdot 16^x - \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot 9^x }= 3\cdot 4^x - 3^x$$
and
$$\sqrt{8\cdot 16^x - \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot 9^x } \leqslant 3\cdot 4^x - 3^x.$$
The correct of the given equation is $$-\log_{\dfrac{3}{4}}\left (3+\dfrac{\sqrt{30}}{2}\right ).$$
I tried

```
Reduce[Sqrt[8 16^x - 1/2 9^x] == 3 4^x - 3^x, x, Reals]
```

> ```
> x == Root[{2 + Sqrt[2] 3^-#1 Sqrt[2^(4 (1 + #1)) - 3^(2 #1)] - 
>  6 E^(2 Log[2] #1 - Log[3] #1) &, 6.0734320063313606675}]
> ```

With inequality, I tried

```
Reduce[Sqrt[8 16^x - 1/2 9^x] <= 3*4^x - 3^x, x, Reals]
```

> ```
> x >= Root[{2 + Sqrt[2] 3^-#1 Sqrt[2^(4 (1 + #1)) - 3^(2 #1)] - 
>  6 E^(2 Log[2] #1 - Log[3] #1) &, 6.0734320063313606675}]
> ```

How can I get the correct solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is based on @Nasser solution but improved to make it more general.

If it helps when there are no roots then let's power both sides to 2. But we have to remeber that this will probably lead to double solution. There is a way to get rid of it too:

**Equality**

```
expr = Sqrt[8 16^x - 1/2 9^x] == 3 4^x - 3^x;

Solve[ Thread[Power[expr, 2], Equal] && expr, x, Reals]
```

> $\left\{\left\{x\to \frac{\log \left(6+\sqrt{30}\right)-\log (2)}{2 \log (2)-\log (3)}\right\}\right\}$

**Inequality**

```
expr = Sqrt[8 16^x - 1/2 9^x] <= 3 4^x - 3^x;

Reduce[Thread[Power[expr, 2], LessEqual] && expr, x, Reals] // Quiet
```

> $x\geq \frac{\log \left(6+\sqrt{30}\right)-\log (2)}{2 \log (2)-\log (3)}$

Answer (score 4):

If you first remove the `sqrt` it seems to help `Reduce`

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{8\left(  16^{x}\right)  -\frac{1}{2}9^{x}}  & =3\left(  4^{x}\right)
-3^{x}\\
\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(  8\left(  16^{x}\right)  -\frac{1}{2}9^{x}\right)    &
=\ln\left(  3\left(  4^{x}\right)  -3^{x}\right)  \\
\ln\left(  8\left(  16^{x}\right)  -\frac{1}{2}9^{x}\right)    & =\ln\left(
\left[  3\left(  4^{x}\right)  -3^{x}\right]  ^{2}\right)  \\
8\left(  16^{x}\right)  -\frac{1}{2}9^{x}  & =3^{2x}+9\left(
4^{2x}\right)  -6\left(  3^{x}4^{x}\right)
\end{align*}

ps. To remove the sqrt, much easier to use suggestion by Kuba. No need for taking logs.

```
Thread[Power[Sqrt[8 16^x - 1/2 9^x] == 3 4^x - 3^x, 2], Equal];
Reduce[%, x, Reals]
```

Now:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The second solution is what you had

```
 Simplify[-Log[3/4, (3 + Sqrt[30]/2)] == %[[2, 2]]]
 (* True *)
```

Comment: @Kuba thanks. Yes, that is easier way to square both sides in order to remove the sqrt root. I just did not know how to do it at the time so took the log of both sides. Will update. thanks.

Comment: No problem. I post my own answer too as I think I can add something new too. :)

Comment: I think, Thread[Power[Sqrt[8 16^x - 1/2 9^x] == 3 4^x - 3^x, 2], Equal];
Reduce[{%, 3 4^x - 3^x >= 0} , x, Reals] // Simplify

Answer (score 1):

Since `Reduce[Sqrt[8 16^x - 1/2 9^x] == 3 4^x - 3^x, x]` gives `Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce` you can only resort to some kind of manipulation.
You would need to make it more generic and robust, but the closest to what you'do with paper and pencil is :

```
eq = Sqrt[8 16^x - 1/2 9^x] - (3 4^x - 3^x) ;
eq2 = (eq /. {3^x -> 4^x y, 9^x -> 4^(2 x) y^2}) (* divide by 4^x *)
eq3 = eq2 /. {x -> 0} (* factor out common  terms assuming they are non-zero *)

aux = Reduce[eq3 == 0, y][[2]]
(* 1/3 (6 - Sqrt[30]) *)

Log[3/4, aux] // N (* recall your change of variable *)
```